# Creating Self-Sizing Table View Cells Dependant on UILabel Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using Swift and am having some issues with making my table view cells self-sizing. From what I have read online the best way is to use:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 138.0
```

I have put this code in but it hasn't seemed to work. I've tried it within viewDidLoad and also the cellForRowAt function. I'm not sure if I'm putting it in the wrong place or if I've set something up wrong. I have also got my auto constraint for the bottom of my UILabel set in relation to the bottom of the container with the expectation that the cell container will grow but the bottom of the UILabel to the bottom on the container will remain constant. Here is the code I currently have in my TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var data = [TextData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadSampleData()   
}


    func loadSampleData() {
        let title1 = TextData(title: "Monday", blurb: "Today is Monday and it's a sunny day", photograph: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mondayone"), article: "Monday Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
        let title2 = TextData(title: "Tuesday", blurb: "Today is Tuesday and it's a bit rainy but will clear up later on today", photograph: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tuesdaytwo"), article: "Tuesday Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur." )
        let title3 = TextData(title: "Wednesday", blurb: "Today is Wednesday and the umbrella should be handy because it's going to be stormy", photograph: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "wednesdaythree"), article: "Wednesday Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
        let title4 = TextData(title: "Thursday", blurb: "Today is Thursday and it's sunny again, no need for any umbrella today!", photograph: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thursdayfour"), article: "Thursday Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")

        data += [title1, title2, title3, title4]
    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TitleTextCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let realData = data[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = realData.title
    cell.bodyText.text = realData.blurb
    cell.photo.image = realData.photograph

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 138.0

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Here is what my tableview currently looks like:
[image: Current Table View]

Here are my current constraints:
[image: Constraints]

Comment: The implication is that your constraints, including your labels, are insufficient to determine the height of the cell from the inside out.

Comment: How would I make sure that my constraints are sufficient? @matt

Comment: The point is that I don't know what your constraints are. You didn't tell _anything_ about them in your question. But they are the issue.

Comment: Hey @matt I've just added a screenshot of my constraints. I hope that proves a bit more helpful.

Comment: What is numberOfLines of body text??

Comment: What constraints are on photo? Width, height, aspect ratio?

Comment: @matt the number of lines is 0 in both the code and in the xcode interface

Comment: @CleverError The photo has width and height constraints and aspect ratio.

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console? It looks to me like your constraints are _over_ determined, in which case I would expect to see error messages in the console.

Comment: @matt Thanks so much for your help. I'm super new to this and completely forgot to be checking the console. It was a constraint error and I was able to see which constraints I needed to change and now it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently photo is preventing your cell from getting taller. Since photo is constrained to both the top and centre of the cell, making the cell taller would always make the image taller, but since the image has a height constraint, photo stops the cell from getting taller.

Remove the Photo.centerY constraint should allow the cell resize based on the label. Or, you could change the constaraint to an inequality (≤ or ≥, cant remember which). That should limit the cell from getting to small if there isn't already another constraint that does that.

Comment: Thank you! This totally makes sense now. I didn't realise that the constraints on the photo would have an effect on the cell resizing. This has definitely improved my knowledge of constraints. Thanks!